# Sprint boot mapping with parameter is not being found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

So I'm trying to make a Java Web application using Springboot and Thymeleaf. Whenever I try to perform a search I get redirected to the error page because I'm getting 404 Not Found.

The form I'm using:

```
<form method="get" th:action="@{/searchBusDP}">
    <p class="mb-3">
        <label for="departurePlace" class="col-form-label">Departure place</label>
        <input type="text" id="departurePlace" name="departurePlace" placeholder="Departure place" class="form-control col-sm-5">
        <!--<span th:if="${error ne null}" th:text="${error}" class="text-danger"></span>-->
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Search bus" class="btn btn-primary">
    </p>
</form>`
```

My controller code:

```
@GetMapping("/searchBus")
public String searchBus() {
    System.out.println("Ik ben in de search");
    return "search-bus";
}

@GetMapping("/searchBusDP")
public String searchBusDP(@RequestParam(name = "departureName") String departurePlace, Model model) {
    try {
        System.out.println("I'm in search DP");
        Iterable<Bus> busses = busService.findAllBussesByDeparturePlace(departurePlace);
        model.addAttribute("busses", busses);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException exc){
        model.addAttribute("error", exc.getMessage());
    }
    return "search-bus";
}
```

Error message I'm getting in IntelliJ:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'departureName' is not present]
```

Comment: when you make the get call how you pass the `departureName` parameter? At your thymeleaf form you do not set  that param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the html page your input type is named departurePlace and in the controller you are calling by a different name try

```
@GetMapping("/searchBusDP")
public String searchBusDP(@RequestParam(name = "departurePlace ") String departurePlace , Model model) {
    try {
        System.out.println("I'm in search DP");
        Iterable<Bus> busses = busService.findAllBussesByDeparturePlace(departurePlace);
        model.addAttribute("busses", busses);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException exc){
        model.addAttribute("error", exc.getMessage());
    }
    return "search-bus";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The name of the RequestParam in the searchBusDP method is mispelled, it should be departurePlace, but it is departureName.

This should fix it:

```java
@RequestParam(name = "departurePlace") String departurePlace
```